# Converting Attributes into Hash from YAML

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

How can I convert `files_copy_to_guest` into a Ruby Hash?

**.kitchen.yml**

```
  'my_cookbook': 
      'files_copy_to_guest':
       - 
          'home/kevin/bin/script.sh'      : '/vagrant/unix_scripts/script.sh'
          'home/kevin/script2.sh'       : '/vagrant/unix_scripts/script2.sh'
```

**cookbooks/my_cookbook/attributes/default.rb**

```
default['kevin']['files_copy_to_guest']     = []
```

**cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb**

```
files = node['kevin']['files_copy_to_guest']   # how to read attribute as Hash?

if files.nil? | files.empty? then
    Chef::Log.warn("node['kevin']['files_copy_to_guest'] is nil or empty!")
end

files.each do |_, value|                
    value.each do |vm_dest, host_src|   
        file vm_dest do 
            owner user
            group user
            mode 0755
            content ::File.open(host_src).read # <<< error on 'value'
        end
    end 
end
```

I tried:

`files = YAML.load(node['kevin']['files_copy_to_guest']`,

but that didn't work. I also [read](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-718) that `files.to_hash` will not work either.

Comment: Then `value` is nil. Work from there.

Comment: but, in my `YAML`, it's a `hash`. in Ruby it would be `{'files_copy_to_guest' => { 'A' => 'B', 'C' => 'D' }}` (as I understand)

Comment: Ignore the YAML for a second. Start from the error and go backwards. That then yields the question, what is `files` *really*?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't know what `node['kevin']['files_copy_to_guest'] `'s type is. (I assumed it'd be a hash given my definition the `.kitchen.yml`.)

Comment: *Inspect it* (`files`) then. I have no idea what the value is either, but apparently it is *not* what is assumed. So find out what it *really* is and work from there.

Comment: Is the stack trace being read correctly? Neither of those directly relate to "<<< error on 'value'".

Comment: Ah, I need to convert YAML into a Hash. That's my real question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
'my_cookbook': 
  'files_copy_to_guest':
   - 
    'home/kevin/bin/script.sh'      : '/vagrant/unix_scripts/script.sh'
    'home/kevin/script2.sh'       : '/vagrant/unix_scripts/script2.sh'
```

It looks to me like the problem is with your YAML. You have a `-` line which denotes the beginning of an array, so your object is coming out looking like this:

```ruby
{
  'my_cookbook' => {
    'files_copy_to_guest' => [
      {
        'home/kevin/bin/script.sh' => '/vagrant/unix_scripts/script.sh',
        'home/kevin/script2.sh' => '/vagrant/unix_scripts/script2.sh'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I think if you ditch the `-` it should work. You can test the output of your YAML with a tool like this: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: Ditching the `-` fixed it. With the `-`, I had a hash of arrays (as you stated). Without it, I had just a `hash`. +1 for the yaml-online link